# Python 3.x on Canopy Express

Tags: enthought, canopy

Are there any issues with installing Python 3.3 after installing Canopy Express (which has Python 2.7)?  I recently installed Canopy to take advantage of the packages it bundles.  I see that it has uses version 2.7 of python, but I would very much like to use the latest and greatest version of Python as I am new to python and just learning it.  However I would like to make sure that installing Python 3.3 doesn't break any of the features of Canopy.

Comment: Enthought Canopy now supports Python 3, as of version 2:
[EDIT: better evidence link]
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/2.0/configure/release-notes.html#new-support-for-python-3-2880

Answer (score 1):

You can install Python 3 *in parallel* to Canopy, but you will not be able to run Canopy on Python 3.